# MSSQL UPDATE script to increment date values in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-update

I'm looking for a way to take dates in a table and update them. Example:

```
ID / DATE
2   2016-02-26 10:15:25.000
3   2016-05-27 09:27:13.000
...
...
9   2016-08-14 22:56:45.000
10  2016-09-05 16:32:24.000
11  2016-12-13 02:13:17.000
```

I'd like to just increment the dates for every date by a fixed # of days (eg. 1 day, 5 days, 10 days)

So, `2016-08-14 22:56:45.000` would be (10 days) `2016-08-24 22:56:45.000`

Essentially what I'm hoping to do is update some 'sample date' to look 'current'. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Nothing on Google about how to ADD DATES to a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just add 10 days to all the dates in a table you can do something like...

```
UPDATE TABLEName 
 SET [DATEColumn] = DATEADD(DAY , 10 , [DATEColumn])
WHERE <Something condition here if needed>
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel foolish. I thought DATEADD was only a function for new lines (didn't know it could be used for updating a line like this). Thanks. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dateadd` function

```
  Update MY_TABLE 
  set [DATE] = dateadd(day,10,[DATE])
```

Read more in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET DATE = DATEADD(day,10,YOUR_TABLE.DATE)
```